# Elastic search removing old indexes based on date by scheduling?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4, elasticsearch-plugin, logstash-configuration

I need to free up space in elastic search host and want to keep last N days data.Is there any way to delete old indexes.
Logstash is creating one index every day and each day there is 15GB data is coming to created index  and we want to keep only last 10 days of data.So is there any way to delete last 11nth day index automatically ??
Index name pattern is like

```
uat_monitoring-2017.01.18
uat_monitoring-2017.01.19
uat_monitoring-2017.01.20
uat_monitoring-2017.01.21
uat_monitoring-2017.01.22 etc
```

And is there any way to compress the elastic search data to minimize disk space usage ?.

Comment: I suggest using the [official curator tool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html) for doing this.

Comment: Thanks Val.Is this for compressing ? or Deleting indexes based on scheduling ?

Comment: The latter. Here are all the actions you can perform with Curator: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/actions.html

Comment: Thanks again.Is it goes as a logstash configuration ? can you please suggest sample of configuration of using curator ?.Can you please take your time to give some basic details as a answer to above question ?

Comment: There is an example in the official document of how to configure Curator for deleting indices: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/ex_delete_indices.html  Try it out and feel free to raise a question if you encounter any issues.